# error while implementing joins in ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, join

I have created two tables in the database ie products and shopping_list.
i have given products a foreign key reference of shopping_list ie product.shopping_list_id.

i am trying to implement joins in ruby on rails but i am getting an error

my routes.rb file is as follows

```
Shop::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :shopping_lists do
    member do
     post 'add'
     get 'delete'
    end

    collection do
     get 'add'
     get 'joins'
     get 'list'     
     post 'get_shopping_lists'
    end
  end

  resources :shopping_lists

  # ---- Contact Routes ------

  resources :products do
    member do
     post 'add'
     get 'delete'
    end

    collection do
     get 'add'
     get 'list'  
     post 'get_products'   
    end
  end  

  resources :products
```

my product.rb is

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base


        attr_accessible :id, :shopping_list_id, :product_name, :product_category, :quantity, :status

        # ------- ASSOCIATIONS --------

        belongs_to :shopping_list


        # ------ VALIDATIONS ------

        validates_presence_of    :id, :product_name

        validates_uniqueness_of  :id

        # -------- SCOPES ----------

        # scope :not_deleted, where("products.deleted = 0")

        # default_scope not_deleted

    end
```

my shopping_list.rb is

```
class ShoppingList < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id, :shopping_list_name, :shopping_list_status, :total_items, :created_by, :last_updated_by

    # ------- ASSOCIATIONS --------

    has_many :products


    # ------ VALIDATIONS ------

    validates_presence_of    :id, :shopping_list_name

    validates_uniqueness_of  :id

    # -------- SCOPES ----------

    # scope :not_deleted, where("shoppinglistsqa.deleted = 0")

    # default_scope not_deleted
end
```

the query I am trying to implement is

```
select shopping_lists.shopping_list_name,shopping_lists.id,products.product_name,products.product_category
from products,shopping_lists
where shopping_lists.id=products.shopping_list_id;
```

can you please help me.

Comment: Your routes are pointless to your question. What is the join?

Comment: select product.id,product.shopping_list_id,shopping_list.shopping_list_name
from products,shopping_lists
where shopping_list.id=product.shopping_list_id
@LoganSerman

Comment: Add the models and database query you want to perform to your question.

Comment: @mind.blank i have edited the question.can you please give me the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
@products = Product.includes(:shopping_lists)
# if you want to get all products + their shopping list

@shopping_list = ShoppingList.includes(:product).find(params[:id])
# if you want to return just 1 shopping_list + it's product

@product = Product.includes(:shopping_lists).find(params[:id])
# if you want to return a specific product + all of it's shopping lists
```

For more info regarding database queries [have a look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).